# Round up in Python above threshold value

Tags: python, rounding

Is there any library or shortcut to achieve the following thing? Sorry if it is a stupid question, not so much familiar with python libraries.

I want to round up if the decimal is above certain threshold instead of .5.

For example, if my threshold is .2, then:

```
input => output
1.2 => 2
1.3 => 2
1.19 => 1
2.21 => 3
2.1 => 2
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
input = 1.19
threshold = 1.2
math.floor(input) if input < threshold else math.ceil(input)

1
```

To make the threshold dynamic:

```
import math
input = 1.19
threshold = 0.2
math.floor(input) if input < (math.floor(input) + threshold) else math.ceil(input)

1
```

Comment: 1.19 should return 1

Comment: yes, sorry, leftover. But the code does what you want. @owninggreendragsdude check now

Comment: we need to change the condition like this which will do the work 
`math.floor(input) if (input - math.floor(input)) < t else math.ceil(input)`

Comment: @jaswanth the code I wrote works fine, no need to change any condition.....

Comment: @Capie I took `t` as `threshold` and the previous answer wouldn't work if `t` is the threshold, that is why I suggested the change

Comment: @jaswanth yes, `t` was input...Forgot to change that one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
threshold = 0.2

def round_up(a):
    if a - int(a) >= threshold:
        return int(a) + 1
    return int(a)
```

Works only for positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer I've found,

```py
import math 

threshold = 0.2
n = 3.4

roundup = math.ceil(n-threshold)
```